# Shed roof protruding nails

Tags: roof, nails

We just paid a contractor to improve our Dutch barn shed. The old nails did not show thru to the inside. However, after replacing the 3 walls and the door and the roof ALL of the nails are protruding and dangerous on the inside of the shed. Because of the particular shape of this structure same nails are eye level. What should be done?  Thank you.

Comment: Cut them off. Or even get the contractor back to cut them off.

Comment: Bend them over with a hammer but it would look sloppy.  An angle grinder would make short work of them.

Comment: Are you talking about roofing or siding nails. If he missed the studs on the siding he should fix that but roofing in my area a nail is required to penetrate the sheeting. If you don’t like that add some internal wall board / peg board to cover the points.

Comment: Back in the "old days", roofing nails were put in by hand, so they would get different lengths based upon the thickness of the "sheeting" that you are nailing the shingles onto. Now days people use pneumatic nail guns and they require longer nails to make them function in the gun, so they end up poking through the sheeting. Usually this is irrelevant because you don't see them anyway. As Ed Beal said, you may need to add some interior wall treatment to hide them. I had that issue on a shed, I used acoustic ceiling tiles because they were easy to push onto the nails.